# How to access all the children of a PreferenceScreen?

Tags: android, preferences

I'm trying to programmatically uncheck all the `CheckBoxPreference` children of a `PreferenceScreen` in my app. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a simpler way - sufficient for my use case - which is to clear the preferences. This can be done by a static method provided a context is passed to it:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().clear().commit();
```

Answer (score 3):

Cannot test it right now... but I'd try something like this:

```
final ListAdapter adapter = getPreferenceScreen().getRootAdapter();
for (int idx = 0; idx < adapter.getCount(); idx++) {
    Object object = adapter.getItem(idx);
    if(object instanceof CheckBoxPreference){
        ((CheckBoxPreference)object).setChecked(false);
    }
}
```